# TERRAFORM Error creating DNS RecordSet: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for 'entity.change.additions[0].rrdata[0]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm have issue about creating google_dns_record_set from template instance, I already set to rrdatas from instance template that i created. buat I have problem that or wrong format rddata.
How to assign multiple ip instance cloud in rrdatas. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

The error 'googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for 'entity.change.additions[0].rrdata[0]' means you can't add the NS record because most probably it already contains an 'A' record with the same name as the on you are trying to add.

As per binding a DNS name to an instance with multiple IPs, [Terraform documentation explains how to do it with the one IP](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/dns_record_set.html). For multiple IPs, [GCP instances do support it](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.2/how-to/networking/using-multiple-ip-addresses), however via Terraform for your scenario you need to reach out to them for additional information.